# MFC/WinCE: CPropertySheet: first property page uninitialized and buttons not working

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-ce

I'm maintaining an MFC app on Windows CE 6.

The app contains a customized property sheet containing 6 property pages. Every page is initialized in OnInitDialog (controls are populated) and contains 2 buttons.

The first property page (i.e. the one that is selected when the property sheet is displayed) is:

- Never initialized.
- Its buttons don't work.
- The sheet handles several events, but no event ever occurs.

If I place the first property page second in the sheet (i.e. swap property pages A and B), then it's B who's not working and A works perfectly.

I've done some hours of trial and error now, and I've got no clue how to fix this. Anybody an idea?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to diagnose without seeing the property sheet and property pages properties. Refer to this example and see if you are able to figure out the problem: [Property Sheets and Property Pages](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/dialogboxes/proppages.htm).

Also refer to this MSDN article on [property sheets and property pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfs4wk4e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Before using any method, please check if the methods are available for WinCE 6.0.